# AJAX Firing, but not executing query on my .PHP page

Tags: php, mysqli

So, the AJAX request is firing but not actually executing the queries. Any help would be appreciated. I am struggling to figure out the issue.

AJAX Function

```
$(".deleteCartProduct").click(function(e){

        e.preventDefault();
         var $form2 = $(this).closest("#form-delete");
         var pid = $form2.find(".pid").val();
         var pcode = $form2.find(".pcode").val();
         var psess = $form2.find(".psess").val();

         $.ajax({
            url: 'deletecart.php',
            method: 'post',
            data: {'pid':pid,'pcode':pcode, 'psess':psess},
            success: function(response){
                $("#alertMsg").html(response);
                load_cart_item_number();

            }
         });

      });

    });
```

form

```
<form action="" id="form-delete" class="">
                                <input type="hidden" class="pid" value="<?= $r['id']; ?>">
                                <input type="hidden" class="pcode" value="<?= $r['productcode']; ?>">
                                <input type="hidden" class="psess" value="<?= $r['sessid']; ?>">
                                <td><button class="btn btn-danger deleteCartProduct">Delete</button></td>
                             </form>
```

EDIT 2: Just realised I didn't include the form. Apologies

EDIT: Deletecart.php code

```
<?php 

require 'config.php';




if(isset($_POST['pid'])){
        $pcode = $_POST['pcode'];
        $psess = $_POST['psess'];

        $stmt = $conn->prepare("DELETE FROM cart WHERE productcode=? AND sessid=?");
        $stmt->bind_param("ss", $pcode, $psess);
        $stmt->execute();
        
        if(!$stmt){
            echo '<div id="alertMsg" class="text-center alert alert-primary alert-dismissible fade show w-50 mt-4 mx-auto" role="alert">
            <strong>Success!</strong>'.$psess.'
           <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
           </div>';
            
        } else if($stmt){

            echo '<div id="alertMsg" class="text-center alert alert-primary alert-dismissible fade show w-50 mt-4 mx-auto" role="alert">
            <strong>Success!</strong>'.$psess.'
           <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
           </div>';
                    }
}
```

Added the deletecart.php above. Apologies for not including it before.

EDIT: I had the form within a table so I believe it wasn't using the right path to get the data from the form values.

Comment: maybe show some of that `deletecart.php` code...

Comment: So, it seems to be firing now but not actually executing what I need it too. Maybe it is to do with deletecart.php. Apologies, I'm a rookie.

Comment: Please update the description of the issue in that case. Also please explain what is executing and what should be.

Comment: Is `$_POST` populated? The case of the `method` might be case sensitive. You need to do more debugging on the PHP for us to help you. Does it enter the `isset`, does the `mysqli` throw an error, what does `response` have after executing?

Comment: when doing `$('#alertMsg').html(response)` you are aware that this is the hierarchy created `<div id="alertMsg"> <div id="alertMsg">...</div></div>`?

Comment: @DevYego To be honest, I am trying to learn about this stuff and I was trying to follow a tutorial and trying to understand it. I didn't know it would do that, no.  I've tried adding error messages. I think it is to do with the handling of the call rather than the call itself. I appreciate all your help and I understand my powers of debugging aren't too great.

Comment: @user3783243 The status of the call is 200, which it states is OK. That is what makes me thing the call is fine. Could it be the way my form is getting the input data from the post?

Comment: I understand. Try starting small; something like just `echo`ing the content of `$_POST` then figure your way from there. May I ask what is the expected scenario?

Comment: @KyleO'Connor Go to the `response` tab and see what the server sent back.

Comment: @user3783243 I've tried to echo the contents of POST and I get the error that it's undefined. I'm assuming this means the data isn't sending correctly. Also,the response tab says there is no response data available.

Comment: @DevYego I am trying to click an item, send a call to delete them via AJAX and update the cart field to show that. I store them in a database whilst in the cart for guests per session for 30 minutes, and for accounts, forever. I'm in the process of writing the guest cart code.

Comment: @KyleO'Connor So likely `if(isset($_POST['pid'])){` is FALSE and this means your whole code wont execute. Try `method: 'POST',`

Comment: @user3783243 I have tried that already, thank you for your suggestion though. I have another AJAX call with a lowercase post method.

Comment: @KyleO'Connor Put an `else` on the `isset` call and see if you enter the `else` block.

Comment: First just comment out the whole `if...else` and replace it with `echo $_POST`. See what is sent back.

Comment: @user3783243 So, I did as you said and it is bypassing the code to the else which means the data isn't being posted if I am correct in thinking.

Comment: Yes, so either `$_POST` is not populated or the `pid` index is not.

Comment: @user3783243 Just realised I also didn't post the code for the form as I said I did. Can you take a look to see if you find any issues?

Comment: You need to look at the form data being sent over seems like it either isn't a POST or `pid` isn't being sent.

Comment: @user3783243 I have tried changing classes as to not let it clash with anything else to rule it out completely. The form is populating when the page loads as the products are showing from the DB. I have no idea why they aren't being retrieved from the form values. I am lost